# Adding Facebook sdk causes opencv file not found

Tags: ios, facebook, opencv

My APP uses opencv framework and works without error. But after I add Facebook sdk, a compile problem occurs. In appname-Prefix.pch,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

Xcode marks the line `#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` and shows `not found`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting 3 hour in the morning, I solved it. Follow the  steps below:

1.remove reference to `opencv2.framework` in my project.

2.add `facebookSDK.framework`.

3.add `opencv2.framework`.

Then the error disappears.

Comment: Thank you! had to do this for DropBoxSDK.framework as well... regular xcode voodoo :/